# Django upload many images to model field

Tags: python, django

I have project in django responsible for creating notes with optional adding images. Now I can add note with maximum one image. I want to allow user add as many images as want, but I don't know how. I tried using ArrayField in model field but it didn't worked. I want to be this way: when user click 'Add image' and explorer shows up he can choose more than one image. And then these images save to one model instance. For example if img field will be ArrayField in database will be: img = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'], I don't want to create as many objects as there is images to upload.

My model:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='note', null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    note_text = models.TextField()
    add_date = models.DateTimeField('added date')
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)
    edit_dates = ArrayField(
        models.DateTimeField('edit dates', blank=True, null=True),
        default=list,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My form:

```
class AddNewNote(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ['title', 'note_text', 'img', ]
```

My view:

```
class CreateNoteView(CreateView):
    model = Note
    template_name = 'notes/add_note.html'
    form_class = AddNewNote

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('show', kwargs={'pk' : self.object.pk})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.add_date = timezone.now()
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CreateNoteView, self).form_valid(form)
```

and add_note.html:

```
{% extends 'notes/base.html' %}

{% block title %} Add new note {% endblock %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 class="display-4">Add new note</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="m-5" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `ImageField`,

```
images = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

The selected images will be available as a list of files when the form is submitted.